# "В школе вечером состоится родительское собрание". Разбор предложения

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор, подлежащее

У нас тут спор возник о разборе предложения.
**В школе вечером состоится родительское собрание.**

Моё мнение:
сказуемое — состоится родительское собрание;
дополнение/обстоятельство — в школе;
обстоятельство — вечером.

Люди утверждают, что подлежащее — собрание.
Кто прав?

Answer (score 3):

Правы те, кто говорит, что "собрание" - подлежащее. 
Отвечает на вопрос *кто?/что?* Это именительный падеж, он в предложении используется (почти) исключительно как падеж подлежащего. Можно еще кучу аргументов привести.

Хотелось бы, однако, понять и ваши аргументы. 
Где в вашем варианте подлежащее? Или хотя бы придумайте предложение, где было бы другое подлежащее и это или подобное дополнение (в том же падеже) при глаголе "состояться". )))

Answer (score 2):

*В школе* и *вечером* — обстоятельства, *состоится* — сказуемое, *родительское* — определение, *собрание* — подлежащее. Впрочем, *родительское собрание* можно рассматривать в качестве нечленимого сочетания и считать подлежащим, тогда *состоится родительское собрание* — это грамматическая основа предложения.